# Which particles can or cannot be entangled?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

Is Quantum entanglement limited to fundamental particles? If it is, then which particles can or cannot be entangled?

Comment: Entanglement can exist between *any* two quantum systems. Do you even know the definition of entanglement?

Comment: Does that mean photons can be entangled?

Comment: Yes, see http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0512048v2.pdf .

Comment: Entanglement is far more common than most people think. For example every time you make a measurement you measure a state of your measureing device. The fact that it tells you something about what you wanted to measure is because the 2 systems were entangled.

Comment: entanglement is a concept that has fluctuated since it appeared. Forget the first wonderful definitions made by popular science books.

Comment: Is the question a theoretical one---in which case @ACuriousMind should make his comment an answer---or is it concerned with what systems can be put into well understood entangled states for experimental purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If thing A has multiple states it can be in, and thing B has multiple states it can be in, then thing A and thing B can, in theory, be entangled. They could, in principle, have been made that way.  And depending on how they interact they might become entangled even if they started out not entangled.

Measurements, in fact, are examples of situations where things become entangled through their interaction.  You design the device so that it and the thing being measured co-evolve into something entangled where the state of device is entangled and correlated with the thing to be measured.  When two systems are not entangled they are called factorizable.  And when they are factorizable then a malicious person can evolve one of the things independent of the other one, so as make them correlated (or not) based on what they choose to do to it.  But if you want them to be correlated, and you entangle them, then you can succeed at your desire to have a correlation without worry about what someone might do to one of them.

Of course if something is already maximally entangled with something else, then this will have to be resolved before you can entangle either of them with something new.  When the former entanglement is resolved, the formerly entangled things can become entangled with the new thing but they sacrifice their entanglement with each other in favor of a mere potentially passing correlation with each other and the opportunity to be entangled with the new thing.

Comment: (1) It is not enough for 2 systems to have multiple states. There **must** be an interacation term in the Hamiltonian. Otherwise the states and the total Hamiltonian are separable for all times. (2) Corelations are not entanglements - non entangled systems and even classical systems can be strongly correlated as well. (3) Entanglement has a property of  **monogamy** - for strong, and especially for maximal entangled states - you can't "factor in the something else, maybe become entangled with both".

Comment: @Alexander I agree that interactions are required, but firstly everything interacts (for instance: gravitationally). Secondly to empirically have two states (not just allegations of different superselection possibilities) you must be able to interact with a measurement device. And thirdly even if two particles don't interact directly a third particle can evolve them into an entangled state.  Even so, I will edit my answer. As for the other issue of monogamy that is what I was referring to, if you want to be entangled with something that is already maximally entangled you must consider that.